# Can anyone provide automate script to add/deploy/update solution in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-package, solution-deployment, powershell-script

Can anyone provide automate script to add/deploy/update solution in SharePoint 2016. So that developers can run this batch file without help from SharePoint Administrators. And please suggest me best tutorials on SharePoint PowerShell Scripting.

Thanks in Advance

Srinivas Dasari

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/tseward/FoundationSync/blob/2013/DeploymentScript/Nauplius.SharePoint.FoundationSync.ps1) is an example you can leverage. This one doesn't have an 'upgrade' function, but rather uninstalls/removes the solution. It also needs to restart the timer service as it is a timer job, which your solution(s) may or may not need to do.